# How to extract substring from nested brackets in JAVA?

Tags: java, string, replace

I have two strings

1. `to_varchar(any_value(attribute))`
2. `any_value(to_varchar(attribute))`

I wish to convert the strings to

1. `cast(any_value(attribute) as varchar)`
2. `any_value(cast(attribute as varchar))` respectively

Is there a simple non-regex logic to achieve the above transformation ?

Comment: If you want to do this in Java, why is Snowflake tagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static String toCastAsVarchar(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("to_varchar\\((([^()]|\\(.*\\))+)\\)", "cast($1 as varchar)");
}
```

And

```
System.out.println(toCastAsVarchar("to_varchar(any_value(attribute))"));
System.out.println(toCastAsVarchar("any_value(to_varchar(attribute))"));
```

output:

```
cast(any_value(attribute) as varchar)
any_value(cast(attribute as varchar))
```